# Renaming type attribute using alter_type

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to rename an attribute in a type that I created... from what I understand... using "ALTER_TYPE" is the correct route to take...

This is because there is a TABLE type that uses the object and dropping then re-adding would mess up a lot of the permissions associated with the type...

I've tried a couple things but haven't been able to find a solid solution...

here is my type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FOO_BAR AS OBJECT
(
   BAR_ID        NUMBER(14)
)
```

and I'm trying to change it to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FOO_BAR AS OBJECT
(
   FOO_ID        NUMBER(14)
)
```

I've tried the following code among others:

```
ALTER TYPE FOO_BAR 
MODIFY ATTRIBUTE BAR_ID rename FOO_ID;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm looking to rename an attribute... not the type itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, There is no such way to rename a type object in oracle and I would love to know if there is any possible way. You need to do this is in broken parts. First Drop the problematic attribute -

```
ALTER TYPE FOO_BAR 
DROP ATTRIBUTE BAR_ID;
```

Then try to add a new object with desired name -

```
ALTER TYPE FOO_BAR 
ADD ATTRIBUTE FOO_ID NUMBER;
```

Comment: "there is a TABLE type that uses the object" - so you would have to include the `invalidate` or `cascade` clause, and either way any information in the old attribute would be lost? I guess you could add the new attribute, update all existing records, then drop the old one, but that seems... painful.

Comment: Understand the complete flow only after seeing your answer. Thank you so much for this topping up.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename the attribute directly. [There is no syntax that supports it.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/ALTER-TYPE-statement.html#GUID-A8B449E7-E3A8-48F4-A4C6-5BB87B1841CD) The only way I can currently see to achieve this, given that you have a table built on top of the type, is to modify what @AnkitBajpai suggested, changing the order of operations and adding an update step:

```
ALTER TYPE FOO_BAR ADD ATTRIBUTE FOO_ID NUMBER(14) CASCADE;

UPDATE FOO_BAR_TAB SET FOO_ID = BAR_ID;

ALTER TYPE FOO_BAR DROP ATTRIBUTE BAR_ID CASCADE;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=584941cc3f7e96f48af491510492db05)

Which is clearly a bit painful...

Answer (score 0):

After talking with some more people and doing a bit more research, it seems like just dropping the table and object type then recreating them would be the best solution.

Unfortunate that there isn't an easier way to rename properties. Pretty big pain adding permissions back on since it's set up for automated deployments.

Thanks everyone for the answers.